# using recaptcha - relative path issue?

Tags: php, relative-path, recaptcha

Forgive my ignorance.
Im trying to set up recaptcha on my site.
looking over the instructions given i see something that seems to be a problem.

the instructions give you this code:

```
 require_once('recaptchalib.php');
```

but this is a relative path, and i was not given anything to download this recaptcha library file, so how is it going to work?

Comment: Wow, I'd hate to see you search the IRS site.

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php

> To use reCAPTCHA with PHP, you can download [reCAPTCHA PHP library](http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/list?q=label%3aphplib-Latest). You will only need one file from there (recaptchalib.php). The other files are examples, readme and legal stuff -- they don't affect functionality.

Comment: Thank you. i wasnt able to find this download. im usually pretty good at that kindof thing. must be having an off day :)